# How to refresh a JTable without setting a new table model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to refresh a `JTable` using the `DefaultTableModel` without accessing the table itself again, but only the existing, but then updated table model.

Yet, I tried to update the table model itself and then notify the model about it (see in the code). For some reason, the table will not update. I do not know, if this is an access problem or if it is just not possible.

```
//in the Gui_Main class 
private static void addTables(){
   JTable tblMain = new JTable(Util_Tables.dtm);
}

//in the Util_Tables class, if the tables needs to be updated
public static DefaultTableModel dtm;

public static void updateTable(){
   dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
   dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: Do you redraw the table after the change?

Comment: Not sure what you’re trying, but creating a new instance of a table model won’t have any affect on any tables. You need to modify the same instance held by the jtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're basic structure is all over the place.  When you create a new instance of `DefaultTableModel` and assign it to `dtm`, this won't be reflected by the `JTable`, as it is still using the instance it first grabbed when it was created.

Exposing `dtm` the way you have, opens it up to undesirable modification and voids one of the principles of OO - encapsulation, where the class is responsible for the management of its properties.  This is also a reason to reconsider the use of `static`

A better start would be to create a getter which returns a single instance of `DefaultTableModel`, so each call to it is guaranteed to return the same instance of `DefaultTableModel` and stops any one else from changing the underlying reference

```
private static void addTables(){
   JTable tblMain = new JTable(Util_Tables.getModel());
}


//in the Util_Tables class, if the tables needs to be updated
private DefaultTableModel model;
public static DefaultTableModel getModel() {
    if (model == null) {
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
    }

}
```

Okay, so how about updating the model?  Well, you need to start by modifying your `updateTable` method, so it can be used to actually update the model in some meaningful way

```
public static void updateTable(Object[][] data, Object[] columnIdentifiers){
   model.setDataVector(data, columnIdentifiers);
}
```

The model will then generate the events it needs itself.  If you find yourself calling the `fireXxx` methods yourself, then it's a good indication that you're doing something wrong.